# How to get data from multi nested JSON file hosted in RESTful API

Tags: c#, webapi

I have created a Web API project with a model class `Issues`.

An `IssuesDbContext` and a `DbSet` have been created using Entity Framework.

```
public class IssueDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IssueDbContext(DbContextOptions<IssueDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

I have one `GET` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Issue>> Get() => await _context.Issues.ToListAsync();
```

This works fine.

Now I am trying to add image information (as a nested node) using a `List<items>` property

1. Added another model class `Imaging`
2. Back in the `Issue` class, added the property

   ```
   public List<Imaging>? images { get; set; }
   ```

When I run the application, the schema looks correct:

[image]

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "created": "2023-08-22T17:20:28.452Z",
    "completed": "2023-08-22T17:20:28.452Z",
    "images": [
      {
        "imagingId": 0,
        "prescriptionId": 0,
        "txSite": "string",
        "imagingType": "string",
        "alignTo": "string",
        "active": true,
        "createdDate": "string",
        "createdBy": "string",
        "modifiedDate": "string",
        "modifiedBy": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But when executed, the result for all the `Images` values is NULL (even though the `Imaging` has data)

[image]

```
"id": 4,
"title": "newest Post of the day",
"description": "Documentation",
"created": "2023-06-02T04:12:06.69",
"completed": "2023-06-02T04:12:06.69",
"images": null
```

What I am doing wrong? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Sorry for this basic question, I've just started to learn.

Comment: How do you know the imaging actually has data? I'm not sure if your question has enough information for us to help you. We can't actually see how any data is pulled to be returned.

Comment: Based on your use of `DbContext`, I'm guessing you simply need to include your Imaging data in your query: try `await _context.Issues.Include(i => i.images).ToListAsync();`  I'd also suggest reading up on [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) and [querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/) data in general.

Comment: Many thanks Brian,
Yes, it was not a good explanation; however, your reply (and experience) provided me the solution.
greatly appreciated :)